# Average of characters and words from rows which have not NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to count some average on text variables, but I am getting errors because of some NaN values in there. I would like not to drop, but just to not consider these rows in counting. I have tried as follows

```
file['C'] = file['text'].notna().str.len()
file['W'] = file['text'].str.split().str.len()
file['E']=file.text.str.endswith('!!!').astype(int)
```

for getting the number of words from text column

```
round(file["C"].mean(),1)
round(file["W"].mean(),1)
round(file["E"].mean(),1)
```

but it is giving me the following error message:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

A sample of data is:

```
   text                       sentiment      value
    more helpful links          positive      1
    I have no homework!!!       positive      1
    what do you think?          neutral       0
    NaN                         neutral       0
```

Comment: What's the type and the content of the `file` variable?

Comment: there are other columns, a mix of categorical and numeric (e.g. sentiment, value,...). I would need only to consider text not null. updated question

Comment: `notna()` returns boolean indexing of a dataframe. So `file['text'].notna().str.len()` needs to be `file[file['text'].notna()].str.len()`

Comment: it does not work. I have got: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' for other columns

Comment: RE: no `str` attribute: use a pandas Series (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `loc` access:

```
notnull_text = file.loc[file['text'].notna(), 'text']

file['C'] = notnull_text.str.len()
file['W'] = notnull_text.str.split().str.len()
# file['W'] = notnull_text.str.count('\s+')+1

file['E'] = notnull_text.str.endswith('!!!').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
                    text sentiment  value     C    W    E
0     more helpful links  positive      1  18.0  3.0  0.0
1  I have no homework!!!  positive      1  21.0  4.0  1.0
2     what do you think?   neutral      0  18.0  4.0  0.0
3                    NaN   neutral      0   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

u have used .str after split which is using str on list that might be the reason.